# Dropping the Indexed Column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas to read the Excel file and then format the columns for my API call.  Here is the excel file:

```
country_code,name
US,Site1-DualBand
US,Site2-DualBand
US,Site3-DualBand
```

This is my script:

I tried the `index_col=None` command and that does nothing.  So I am trying `index_col=0`.

[image: This is what it does]

If I add this to convert it to a csv first, it cleans it up:

```
 rft_csv = pd.DataFrame.to_csv(rft)
```

[image]

If I try to convert that csv into a `dict` or `json` I get an error and I am unable to proceed.  This is the final format I am trying to get to:

```
{"country_code": "US", "name": "Site1-DualBand"}
{"country_code": "US", "name": "Site2-DualBand"}
{"country_code": "US", "name": "Site3-DualBand"}
```

Here is the full code:  NOTE:  I did try `pd.DataFrame.to_json(record)`, and it is not giving me the desired results.  By index I mean pandas adding `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` in the column far left.

```
rft = pd.read_excel('sitedata.xlsx', sheet_name='rftemplates', index_col=0, usecols=['country_code', 'name'])
print(rft)
rft_csv = pd.DataFrame.to_csv(rft)
print(rft_csv)
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean with dropping the index column, but the desired outcome can be achieved with [`df.to_dict('records')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) (alternatively `df.to_json(orient="records")`).

Comment: Can you upload all your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the output you want.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mycsv = StringIO("""country_code,name
    US,Site1-DualBand
    US,Site2-DualBand
    US,Site3-DualBand
""")

df = pd.read_csv(mycsv, index_col=0)

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df.to_json(orient='records'))
```

Comment: So the pickle here is that I am reading this data from an excel file.

Comment: Thank you @inabeo.  I was able to utilize your code with some modification.